# Get final generated HTML on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm programming an dynamic website that simulates pokemon-style fights with Digimon. I need to get the current, postprocessed, postcss,postjs etc HTML file in order to test new features.

The following is the website visual while running the html file (one browser runs js and css).
[image]

The following is what I get when just copying the HTML from the browsers inspect element. 
[image]

Is there a way to easily get the post generated HTML? I know inspect-element HTML doesn't storage js/css changes, but the browser has to somehow generate the webpage , the final HTML must be somewhere

Comment: Element inspection shows the current state of the site including css and js, at least in chrome. View-Source displays the original src retrieved from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish; copying just the HTML will unlink JS and CSS. The developer tools do show the HTML representation of the DOM state, which means JS changes are applied to it (as opposed to the Ctrl+U source view, which shows the original HTML received from the server). Still, why exactly are you copying the HTML in the first place? Where are you copying it? What's the point?

Comment: Are you programming the game yourself?

Comment: @Kokodoko yes, i am

Comment: (at least, trying ahah)

Comment: That's great fun! But it's better to show your own code and tell us the specific problem you're having.

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm building the whole website as a single page. Before that screen, the player chosen his starting digimon. I created a "ghost" div on the html, and i'm using .innertext + event listeners to keep the page changing. I need to design the "arena" where the digimon imgs, theirs lifes, name etc are displayed, in order to .innertext the ghost div with the complete arena html. Since the page is dynamic, it is time wasting to play the whole game to get to this point, and the solo ghost-div in a separeted html file doesn't behave the same way, since there are more elements on the screen.

Comment: Exactly what I thought: this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking "how do I use X to accomplish Y?", but X isn't the proper tool in the first place. What you should be asking instead is "how can I skip to a specific game state to easier test newly implemented features?", because that is the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: So you want a shortcut to test a certain state of the game. The best way to do that is to implement variables that decide which part of the game is currently running. Then you can set that variable to `arena` (and set scores and such to fake values) and then you can test the arena right away, without going through all the previous screens.

Comment: @ChrisG i don't think many people code games the way i'm doing in this project. Most people would be using some p5, react, flash, unity, etc to make things easier. I'm harcoding the transitions, since it's an educational project. Having to download a current state of a dynamic webpage is, i believe, more common

Comment: No... it's not common at all... (and even if it was, it's still a bad idea :) It is pretty common to code a game entirely in Javascript without any library. I would advise you to post some of your own code and ask how to jump ahead to a certain state, you'll get more useful answers that way.

Comment: Sorry, but the framework / language or type of project doesn't matter; your approach is a bad idea. When I started out 25 years ago I did the exact same thing. The sooner you learn how to do it properly, the better. The typical approach is to completely separate game state from presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to close the topic :

Try right click -> Save As. It should generate a folder with an HTML file and all the scripts you need

As mention by @Doğancan Arabacı :

> it's not guaranteed to get everything exactly as you see in a different page. There might be ajax requests, which will be responded only to specific domain. In that case your page would look different. There might be certain cookies, session parameters etc. So, you can probably copy 99% of the page but never guarantee that it'll be 100% same

Comment: This answers the question at face value but completely ignores the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is impossible. 
What you see in your browser is not post generated HTML. Well, it's not the only thing there. There is CSS rules applied, there is javascript changes. Even your javascript might add CSS or more scripts etc. 
To get the state you want, your page/html files should do exact same things.

Comment: Is there any tool that generates an html file with inline css/js scripts/style-changes from a website?

Comment: Try right click, Save As. It should generate a folder with an HTML file and all the scripts you need

Comment: you can always save all files as suggested, but it's not guaranteed to get everything exactly as you see in a different page. There might be ajax requests, which will be responded only to specific domain. In that case your page would look different. There might be certain cookies, session parameters etc. So, you can probably copy 99% of the page but never guarantee that it'll be 100% same

Comment: @toto1911 that's exactly what i needed. Please answer the question so i can close the topic

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı I don't know ajax ahaha but thank you!

Comment: This answer should've been a comment.